# Get all subarrays of a list in a circle

Tags: python

How to get all the sub arrays from a list where the last element continues with the first element as a circular list?

```
Array = [0,1,1,0,0,1]
```

Sub arrays of length 3

```
[0,1,1], [1,1,0], [1,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,1]
```

Comment: @sudden_appearance Please don't post answers in the comments; post an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use zip with rotated copies of the array offset by one:

```
Array  = [0,1,1,0,0,1]
size   = 3

*result, = zip(*(Array[i:]+Array[:i] for i in range(size)))

print(result)

[(0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)]
```

Or leveraging negative indexing to automatically wrap to the beginning of the list:

```
result = [[Array[p] for p in range(i,i+size)] for i in range(-len(Array),0)]

print(result)

[[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, the simplest option is to [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) N-1 elements to the end of the list, then use a standard method for getting overlapping chunks, like [`more_itertools.windowed`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.windowed).

```
from itertools import chain
from more_itertools import windowed

a = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
n = 3

result = list(windowed(chain(a, a[:n-1]), n))
```

```
[(0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)]
```

---

If N could be large, it might be good to avoid making a slice (i.e. a copy of that part of the list). You can use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) instead:

```
from itertools import chain, islice
...

result = list(windowed(chain(a, islice(a, n-1)), n))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `sliding_window` recipe from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```py
from collections import deque
from itertools import islice, tee, chain

def sliding_window(iterable, n):
    it = iter(iterable)
    a, b = tee(it, 2)

    it = chain(a, islice(b, n-1))

    window = deque(islice(it, n), maxlen=n)

    if len(window) == n:
        yield tuple(window)
    for x in it:
        window.append(x)
        yield tuple(window)



array = [0,1,1,0,0,1]

list(sliding_window(array, 3))
[(0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is using `islice` and `cycle` from itertools, and `zip`:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

array = [0,1,1,0,0,1]
it = zip(array, islice(cycle(array), 1, None), islice(cycle(array), 2, None))
print(list(it))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you reach the end you can circulate you list:

```
lst=[0,1,1,0,0,1]

def prt_lst(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        print(i, end=" ")
        print(lst[i])

def new_order(lst):
    elm= lst.pop()
    lst.insert(0, elm)
    elm= lst.pop()
    lst.insert(0, elm)
    return lst

def sub_lst(lst, i):
    return [lst[0+i],lst[1+i], lst[2+i]]

def run(lst):
    run = range(len(lst)-2)
    for i in run:
        s = sub_lst(lst, i)
        print(s)
    
start = 3
stop = 0
  
while True:
    stop += start
    start -= 1
    
    #prt_lst(lst)
    run(lst)
    new_order(lst)

    if start == 0:
        break
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is with a simpler list comprehension, and without `itertools`:

```
array = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
LENGHT = 3

[(2 * array)[pos:pos + LENGHT]  for pos in range(len(array))]
# Lists output
# [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]

# Other option
[tuple((2 * array)[pos:pos + LENGHT])  for pos in range(len(array))]

# Tuples output 
# [(0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)]
```